# SvelteKitAuth & Keycloak - OperationProcessingError: "response" is not a conform Authorization Server Metadata response

Tags: asp.net-core, sveltekit

I modified the https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/tree/main/apps/examples/sveltekit  demo to use Keycloak as provider instead Github, but whenever I try to login I get the following error:

```
[auth][error] OperationProcessingError: "response" is not a conform Authorization Server Metadata response
    at Module.processDiscoveryResponse (file:///Users/humberto/Downloads/next-auth-main/apps/examples/sveltekit/node_modules/oauth4webapi/build/index.js:215:15)
    at getAuthorizationUrl (file:///Users/humberto/Downloads/next-auth-main/apps/examples/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/signin/authorization-url.js:19:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Module.signIn (file:///Users/humberto/Downloads/next-auth-main/apps/examples/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/signin/index.js:10:56)
    at async AuthInternal (file:///Users/humberto/Downloads/next-auth-main/apps/examples/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:58:24)
    at async Proxy.Auth (file:///Users/humberto/Downloads/next-auth-main/apps/examples/sveltekit/node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:104:29)
    at async Module.respond (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:282:20)
    at async file:///Users/humberto/Downloads/next-auth-main/apps/examples/sveltekit/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:510:22
```

[image]

Here is my updated `hooks.server.ts` file:

```
import { SvelteKitAuth } from "@auth/sveltekit"

import Keycloak from "@auth/core/providers/keycloak"
import { KEYCLOAK_URL, KEYCLOAK_REALM, KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID, KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET } from "$env/static/private"

const KEYCLOAK_ISSUER = `http://${KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}`
// e.g., http://keycloak.local/realms/svelte

export const handle = SvelteKitAuth({
  providers: [Keycloak({ clientId: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET, issuer: KEYCLOAK_ISSUER })],
})
```

My `.env` file:

```
KEYCLOAK_URL=keycloak.local
KEYCLOAK_REALM=svelte
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=demo
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET=MiKsJyuLF8ZntC18uIqqMBZ529veebTr
AUTH_SECRET=5ea1a6bd5fad1eb1d9c4c5a79893d3f8
```

Any idea what is root of the problem?

Thanks for any help in advanced!

//////// ///////// ///////// /////// /////////// //////// //////// //////

I'm running a local instance of Keycloak where I created a realm: svelte

[image]

with a client: `demo`

[image]

a single user: `slvelte` that is a part of the `dev` group

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more what issue exactly you are having with? Its hard to understad your configuration? Have you checked the configuration if that correct?